# tuple' object cannot be interpreted as an integer in autopy

Tags: python, python-3.x, autopy

i try to use this code but it show "tuple' object cannot be interpreted as an integer"

```
import autopy
creen = autopy.bitmap.capture_screen();
po = tuple(screen.find_color((255,117,99),0.05));
```

Answer (score 1):

find_color expects two argument, a `color` and a `float`.  You can convert your tuple to a color as such:

```
import autopy
screen = autopy.bitmap.capture_screen()
po = screen.find_color(autopy.color.rgb_to_hex(255,117,99),0.05)
```